# How to save changes in App.config?

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration

I am trying to save settings in the `App.config` file, but am getting `InvalidOperationException`. I am following the example from
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx).

This is my code:

```
private void button_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Key = textBox_Key.Text.Trim();
    string Value = textBox_Value.Text.Trim();//bug: should use control textBox_NewValue
    if (Key != "" && Value != "")
    {
        try
        {
            // write new value to app.config:
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
            if (settings[Key] == null)
                settings.Add(Key, Value);
            else
                settings[Key].Value = Value;
            //config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); //-->Exception: Method failed with unexpected error code 1.
            config.Save(); //-->Exception: Method failed with unexpected error code 1.
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
            // feedback:
            textBox_Value.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Key];
            textBox_NewValue.Text = "";
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException exc)
        {
        }//debug breakpoint
        catch (Exception exc)//--> InvalidOperationException
        {
        }//debug breakpoint
    }
    return;
}
```

Might there be something that it is not possible to update a file like App.config while it is in use and locked by the running application?

---

As commented below, my question seems a duplicate of [ConfigurationManager.save() fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120361/configurationmanager-save-fails). On a local disk and / or running the .exe directly (not in VS Debug mode) the exception does not occur.

Unfortunately, I do also not see an updated value in App.config, but that seems an unrelated question.

---

After fixing my own bug (see comment above) I can confirm that the new value is indeed written, to the file {app}.exe.config, on a non-shared disk.

Comment: What does the `InvalidOperationException` say?

Comment: the Message was, like I mentioned: `Method failed with unexpected error code 1.` and there was no InnerException. Not much help indeed.

Comment: try adding settings.Remove(key); before adding

Comment: @Sachu Thanks for your suggestion. However, I just tried, and the same exception occurs.

Comment: is the config file on a network drive or your local machine?

Comment: @DrewJordan It is on a shared drive with a VirtualBox virtual machine. I will try to do a test on a local disk.

Comment: @Roland i tried in my local system and above code is working fine.

Comment: yeah, this said the same thing, although it doesn't mention a fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120361/configurationmanager-save-fails

Comment: @Sachu I tried to run without the VS debugger, and then there is no exception. But the new value is also not saved in App.config. Did you manage to save a new value?

Comment: I am testing now in a local dir and without debugger, and there is no exception. But also no updated app.config. In fact, I did a clean rebuild and in bin/debug there are all kinds of files, and an .exe, but no app.config. Still, I am able to get config key/value pairs (not in the above code). So if I don't see App.config, where does it want to save updates???

Comment: @Roland u r write it is not getting saved.. look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871114/writing-key-value-pairs-into-app-config-file) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357240/change-the-value-in-app-config-file-dynamically) hope it helps

Comment: @Roland I posted an answer that should address the problems you were having with finding the changes to the config file. What makes you think that you need a custom xml file? Are you trying to save settings that are shared between users?

Comment: @DrewJordan Thanks for your answer. Due to holiday / weekend I will try it next Monday or Tuesday. As for your question: this app is for a single-user computer.

Comment: np. If you're using ClickOnce, it *does* install separately for each user, but in most cases that's what you want anyhow. No need to use a custom xml file; you can use app.config here. You may also want to have a look at `Properties.Settings` as you might run into issues writing to the application's directory if the user isn't an admin: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Winforms projects, when you compile your project the `app.config` file is copied to the output directory as `<appname>.exe.config`. Any runtime changes made to the configuration are made to this file (and not the `app.config` in your source code directory). This is the file that should be distributed with your application; if you're using ClickOnce this file will go with your application to become the config file used by the deployment.

Also worth noting for debugging purposes (which is really your use case here for the moment), as long as you're running inside Visual Studio, the actual file modified will be `<appname>.vshost.exe.config`. You can verify this by running inside VS and checking the .vshost.exe.config file, and then running the .exe from the directory directly and monitoring the .exe.config file.

As for the `InvalidOperationException`, there is a known problem with [trying to access the app.config file in a VirtualBox shared folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120361/configurationmanager-save-fails), although the only solution seems to be to use a local directory.

Comment: if you could add your remark about the shared disk to your solution, I would be glad to accept it.