# Values not adding to appSettings in app.config

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I've stepped through my code and all seems to be working. I'm taking two values from an async response and I'm trying to write it to my `appSettings` in `app.Config` however....when I force refresh of my app.config, there are no values there at all.

Code for getting and writing values to `app.config` is

```
public void Authenticated(Action success, Action<Exception> failure)
{
    Client.GetAccessTokenAsync((accessToken) =>
    {
        UserToken = accessToken.Token;
        UserSecret = accessToken.Secret;

        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;

        if (settings["userLoginSecret"] == null && settings["userLoginToken"] == null)
        {
            settings.Add("userLoginSecret", UserSecret);
            settings.Add("userLoginToken", UserToken);
        }
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);

        if (success != null) success();
    },
    (error) =>
    {
        if (failure != null) failure(error);
    });
}
```

And my `app.Config` file is staying like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="userLoginToken" value=""/>
  <add key="userLoginSecret" value=""/>
</appSettings>`
```

Any help much appreciated....

Comment: Are your Appsetting configured for Application or User; Application settings are read only IIRC

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save changes in App.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219050/how-to-save-changes-in-app-config)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ConfigurationManager`, consider adding Settings in 
`Project\Properties\Settings.settings`

Make sure the scope of your setting is "User"

Then you can write to the settings via code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName = "Value";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

To read the setting:

```
String value = Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName;
```

Comment: My application isn't giving me access to Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName, I'm getting 'The name Properties does not exist in the current context'.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running your application in Visual Studio in debug the configuration file that is actually modified is **appname.vshost.exe.config**, so be sure to check the correct file.

When you compile the project the file to be modified is instead **appname.exe.config** and not the app.config inside the source code folder.

If you want to test the normal .exe.config file during Debug you should uncheck the box "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" in the "Debug" tab of the project properties.

Moreover, if in your app.config file the two keys already exist, with this snippet of code:

```
 if (settings["userLoginSecret"] == null && settings["userLoginToken"] == null)
    {
        settings.Add("userLoginSecret", UserSecret);
        settings.Add("userLoginToken", UserToken);
    }
```

you insert the values only if the condition is satisfied and the keys are not present. If you want to update the values also if they have been already inserted you should add:

```
else
    {
        settings["userLoginSecret"].Value = UserSecret;
        settings["userLoginToken"].Value = UserToken;
    }
```